# Why is the Stopping Theorem interesting?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

The theorem for discrete-time martingales is as follows:

Let $X=(\Omega,\mathcal{F},(\mathcal{F}_n)_n,(X_n)_n,\mathrm{P})$ be a supermartingale and $\tau_1,\tau_2$ two a.s. bounded stopping times on the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_n$ with $\tau_1\leq \tau_2$ a.s.
Then the r.v.'s $X_{\tau_1}$ and $X_{\tau_2}$ are integrable and $E(X_{\tau_2}\ |\ \mathcal{F}_{\tau_1} )\leq X_{\tau_1}$

Probably there's something I'm not aware of, because it seems too much obvious to me:
By definition of martingale $X_n$ has to be integrable for every $n$, so it should be for $\tau_n$ too. And also by definition of supermartingale shouldn't $E(X_{\tau_2}\ |\ \mathcal{F}_{\tau_1} )\leq X_{\tau_1}$ be true just because $\tau_1\leq \tau_2$?

Comment: Why is it obvious to you that ${\rm E}[X_n]<\infty$ for all $n$ implies ${\rm E}[X_\tau]<\infty$ for a stopping time $\tau$? Recall that $X_{\tau}(\omega):=X_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$ for $\omega\in \{\tau<\infty\}$ so the index also depends on $\omega$.

Comment: Oh crap, I was intending $X_\tau=X_n$ with $n=\tau$. That was a quite stupid error! Thank you for having noticed me about this.